# Javascript Error - Undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to create a format for a graph. When I try to do so I am getting an `undefined` with `console.log` before the data. Here's my code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var graphData = new Array();
    $.getJSON("ds/js.json", function (Data) {
        dataLength = returnedData.data.length;
        var x = new Array();
        var y = new Array();
        var mytext, dataa, f;
        for (i = 0; i < dataLength; i++) {
            x[i] = Data.data[i].avgPrice;
            y[i] = Data.data[i].numProducts;
        }
        for (var a = 0; a < 6; a++) {
            mytext = "x:" + x[a] + "," + "y:" + y[a] + "}" + "," + "{";
            dataa = dataa + mytext;
        }
        console.log(dataa);
        var f =
            "[{data : [{" + dataa;
        console.log(f);
    });
    drawGraph(graphData);
});
```

Console output :

> undefinedx:87.6,y:85},{x:116.08,y:61},{x:113.11,y:49},{x:181.37,y:65},{x:138.14,y:74},{x:66.03,y:89},x:66.03,y:89},{

What am I doing wrong here? And also I want a separate format for a=5, that stops the ", {" coming at the end.

Comment: u will have to show the `returnedData` here.!

Comment: You need to put the call to "drawGraph()" **inside** the `$.get()` callback function.

Comment: u did not initialize variable dataa

Comment: Initialise `dataa` to an empty string before using it in the loop. Why does the second loop assume `6` items? Also, though it isn't causing the problem you mentioned, you should declare _all_ of your variables with `var` or they'll be globals - which could lead to other problems later.

Comment: What are you building the string for? Looks like using `JSON.stringify` would be simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be building an object through string concatenation like that. I'd recommend actually building up an array of objects like so:

```
var dataa = [];
for (var a = 0; a < 6; a++) {
    var newObj = {x: + x[a], y: + y[a]};
    dataa.push(newObj);
}
```

And then to generate the `f` you currently have:

```
var f = JSON.stringify([{data: dataa}]);
```

Comment: This is definitely more than What I have expected.. Amazing! thanks a lot colin !!!!

Comment: Hi. I have some problem with the result. the output is [{"data":[{"x":87.6,"y":85},{"x":116.08,"y":61},{"x":113.11,"y":49},{"x":181.37,"y":65},{"x":138.14,"y":74},{"x":66.03,"y":89}]}]
... I want it like the same without quotes.. can u help me pls?

Comment: What are you trying to use the string for?

Answer (score 5):

When you do this:

```
for  (var a=0;a<6;a++){
    mytext = "x:" +x[a] + "," + "y:" +y[a] + "}" + "," + "{" ;
    dataa=dataa+mytext; 
}
```

you're performing string concatenation with `dataa` and `mytext`. However, in the first iteration of that `for` loop `dataa` has not yet been initialised, and the string representation of that is `undefined`.

When you declare the `dataa` variable initialise it as an empty string instead:

```
var mytext,dataa = '',f;
```

---

As an aside, it's important to remember that `$.getJSON()` makes an asynchronous request for data. If the result of that call is necessary for the `drawGraph` function to perform correctly then your code isn't going to function as you might expect (though with what you've posted in the question there's no definitive indication this is the case).

The `$.getJSON()` function will finish executing immediately (after initiating the request), allowing `drawGraph` to execute, but there's no guarantee that the request will have received a response and the processing of `returnedData` will have occurred; in fact there's a very strong possibility that won't have happened.

Comment: It's also going to be important to deal with the asynchronous nature of the `$.get()` call.

Answer (score 0):

```
    dataa = dataa + mytext;
--------------^
```

this is `undefined` initially

You need to do this -

```
 var mytext, dataa = "", f;
```